# How do I find out who deleted (removed) an Iteration from Rally?

Tags: excel, rally, revision-history

I am using the Excel Add-in to look at revision history.  I would like to locate the information (User, Date, Time, etc.) when an Iteration in Rally was "removed".  I am able to obtain this but get too many rows.

I want to know when an Iteration is removed from a project.

I don't want to know when the Iteration value is changed on a User Story.

Right now I am getting rows relating to both situations.

Any hints?

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a specific single place to look for this, nor a single Webservices query that you can run to provide this information. Your best bet is to find a Work Product (User Story, Defect, etc.) that was scheduled into the Iteration, and examine its Revision History. There will be an entry similar to:

`ITERATION removed [Iteration 3] 2013-May-15 12:19:43 PM America/Denver  Mark W`

That includes Date/Time and User that performed the delete.

This likely precludes Excel being the tool of choice to do this query as it would require you to query and parse many, many Revision History entries throughout your User Stories of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.  This may take a little more effort because the situation seems to happen too often.

Comment: Sorry for the hassles. Rally's coarse permissions model and the lack of traceability around deletion of releases and iterations can definitely be problematic.